# python code error for gTTS (google text to speech) module

Tags: python, valueerror

when I enter the command from

```
.gtts import gTTS

tts = gets.tts.gTTS(text='Hello', lang='en')
tts.save("hello.mp3")'
```

it comes up with an error code saying

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

I have tried to fix my gtts for a while now as before I got an error code saying

> no module named 'gtts'

but I had it installed. so I went to this and found out if I use `.gtts` it will come up with the other error code that I believe is better than the last error code I got

Answer (score 1):

```
from gtts import gTTS
myobj = gTTS(text="Hello', lang='en')
myobj.save('hello.mp3')
```

the above should work. gtts version should be 1.1.2